# Ansible tasks installing undesired packages

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

In my ansible playbook I have a few roles running tasks that install lots of different packages. Some of these packages seem to be installing:

**modemmanager**, **wpasuppclient**, **snapd**, and **apache**

I'm quite new to using the `when:` condition in ansible. Is there a way that I could add a when condition in my ansible tasks that prevent them from installing these packages when running my playbook?

pseudocode:

`- name: installing packages
   when: if modemmanager, wpasuppclient, snapd, and apache are getting installed stop them from being installed?
   apt: pkg={{item}} state=latest
   with items:
       list of items`

Another thought I had is that is there a way that I could use the `state` variable to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a variable that is a list of the packages to be excluded, add it in the `vars` section of the playbook:

```
vars:
  package_exclusion_list: [modemmanager, wpasuppclient, snapd, apache]
```

update your task adding a `when` condition:

```
- name: installing packages
  apt: pkg={{item}} state=latest
  when: item not in package_exclusion_list
  with items:
       list of items
```

hope it helps

Side quest:

if you want to run a batch of "simple" tasks (as you explained in the comments), you can use the `include_tasks`.

example:

```
  - name: include tasks
    include_tasks: various_tasks.yml
    with_items: 
      - "{{ packages_to_install }}"
```

but pay attention, the `various_tasks.yml` should refer to each of the `packages_to_install` items with `item`.

`various_tasks.yml` example:

```
---
- name: print items name
  debug:
    var: item

- name: print items name #2
  debug:
    msg: "variable value: {{ item }}"
```

obviously, if you try to add in this various_tasks file some loop that will have to use its own `items`, then it will have a conflict.

Comment: Will the packages I'm installing be installed if they try to install items in my exclusion list? Because I still need these packages I just don't want them to install any of the ones in that list

Comment: yes, if there are dependencies they will be installed. this `when` is instructing ansible to skip running `apt install` in case the "item" name is one of the exclusion list

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Quick followup, if I have a bunch of different tasks is there a way to put the when statement as an overhead so I don't have to repeat it for every task?

Comment: there is the `include_tasks` module, probably its what you need, but i havent used it with a loop before, should work i guess.

Comment: coming back to it. This solution works but is pretty clunky (i haven't figured out the include_tasks, but i'm looking into it now.) thanks again!